dotnet android layout binding (not MAUI not Xamarin)
I'm looking for documentation to do layout binding but for android dotnet.
All examples i found talk about Xamarin (deprecated may 2024) or MAUI which does not cover this thread.
Any help, doc, snippet will be appreciate.
Thanks
